# How to connect to Mysql from Lua with local-infile=1

Tags: mysql, lua, load-data-infile, my.cnf, luasql

I am connecting to a mysql database from lua using :

```
mysql = require "luasql.mysql"
local env = mysql.mysql()
local conn = env:connect(database,userName,password)
```

but the option local-infile is not activated so my requests using LOAD DATA don't work.
I tried to put the line

```
local-infile = 1
```

in the file my.cnf in the field [client] but it still doesn't work.
FYI : I am using linux and mysql 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same situation last week. The query `LOAD DATA INFILE` worked on Mac OSX, but I could not make it work on Ubuntu. The only way I found to make it work was adding one line of code to the LuaSQL project and recompiling it.

I used the MySQL driver's function `mysql_options` (you can check its prototype in the `mysql.h` file, probably located at `/usr/include/mysql`) to enable the `local-infile`. You can check the code at the [repository](https://github.com/rafaeldias/luasql).

To compile and install this workaround, you should download the files:

```
$ wget https://github.com/rafaeldias/luasql/archive/master.zip
$ unzip master.zip
```

To compile and install :

```
$ cd luasql-master/
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

**Note**: Depending on where your Lua and MySQL folders are located, you may need to set the proper values for the LUA_LIBDIR, LUA_DIR , LUA_INC , DRIVER_LIBS and DRIVER_INCS in the `config` file within the LuaSQL folder.

Hope it helps.